# Why Createprocess returns NULL?

Tags: windows, windows-7, process, operating-system

I have following code`

```
STARTUPINFOA cif={sizeof(cif)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
CreateProcessA( "C:\Windows\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL , NULL, NULL,     &cif, &pi);
cout << pi.hProcess <<  endl;
```

It outputs NULL, why? what is wrong? if i write`

```
STARTUPINFO cif={sizeof(cif)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
CreateProcess( L"C:\Windows\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL , NULL, NULL, &cif, &pi);
cout << pi.hProcess << endl;
```

it also outputs NULL, what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"C:\Windows\notepad.exe" contains a newline character, because "\n" is special.  Use forward slashes in your paths, it works even on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, i forget about it :(

Comment: Forward slashes don't always work, it depends on the context.  Better to get into the habit of properly quoting the backslashes.